# How to send a search request using OneDrive SDK for Android

Tags: java, android, rest, httprequest, onedrive

I am desperately trying to understand how to use the OneDrive SDK for Android.
The sample apps only describe picking, saving or exploring.
I have implemented the explorer available here:
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-explorer-android

and in the end, I have this kind of code:

```
final IOneDriveService oneDriveService = oneDriveHelper.getOneDriveService();
final Callback<Item> itemCallback = getItemCallback(app);
oneDriveService.getItemId(mItemId, mQueryOptions, itemCallback);
```

where

```
mItemId="root";
```

I tried changing the mQueryOptions by doing this

```
mQueryOptions.put("q", "myKeyWord");
```

without success (it's just listing the root)

I tried replacing mItemId with:

```
"root:/view.search"
```

without any more success.

http://onedrive.github.io/items/search.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally understood how it all worked.

So since the ApiExplorer is just a sample, we need to add more functionalities by hand into it.

In the Module called **onedriveaccess**, go to the package **com.microsoft.onedriveaccess.model** and add the following file **ItemList.java**

```
package com.microsoft.onedriveaccess.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.util.List;

public class ItemList {
    @SerializedName("value")
    public List<Item> itemList;
}
```

Then in **com.microsoft.onedriveaccess.IOneDriveService.java**, add the following piece of code:

```
@GET("/v1.0/drive/{item-id}/view.search")
@Headers("Accept: application/json")
void searchForItemId(@Path("item-id") final String itemId,
        @QueryMap    Map<String, String> options,
        final Callback<ItemList> itemCallback);
```

now we can generate a search query as follows:

```
  /**
 * The query option to have the OneDrive service expand out results of navigation properties
 */
private static final String EXPAND_QUERY_OPTION_NAME = "expand";

/**
 * Expansion options to get all children, thumbnails of children, and thumbnails
 */
private static final String EXPAND_OPTIONS_FOR_CHILDREN_AND_THUMBNAILS = "children(select=id, name)";


private final Map<String, String> mQueryOptions = new HashMap<>();


private Callback<ItemList> getItemsCallback(final Context context) {
    return new OneDriveDefaultCallback<ItemList>(context) {
        @Override
        public void success(final ItemList items, final Response response) {
            //mItem = items.itemList.get(0);

            //Do what you want to do

            for(Item item: items.itemList){
              Log.v(TAG, "array:"+item.Id+"--- "+item.Name);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(final RetrofitError error) {

            //Log.v(TAG, "Item Lookup Error: " + mItemId);

        }
    };
}


public void searchQuery(String query){
    mQueryOptions.put(EXPAND_QUERY_OPTION_NAME, EXPAND_OPTIONS_FOR_CHILDREN_AND_THUMBNAILS);
    mQueryOptions.put("q", query);

    final IOneDriveService oneDriveService = oneDriveHelper.getOneDriveService();
    final Callback<ItemList> itemCallback = getItemsCallback(app);
    oneDriveService.searchForItemId(mItemId, mQueryOptions, itemCallback);

}
```